# AWS-SES rails gems

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, amazon-web-services, actionmailer, amazon-ses

I have been trying gems for AWS SES service:
[aws-ses](https://github.com/drewblas/aws-ses), [Amazon-SES-Mailer](https://github.com/abronte/Amazon-SES-Mailer) but both gems don't work. They are raise exception:

```
AWS::SES::ResponseError: AWS::SES Response Error: SignatureDoesNotMatch - The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided. Check your AWS Secret Access Key and signing method. Consult the service documentation for details.
```

I spent 10 hours to solve this problem but I couldn't find out. Anybody who has solved this problem, please help me!

Comment: are you using the correct AWS secret key??

Comment: yes. of course, I set it up correctly. And I have been setting up ActionMailer for  it with patch Http module and it worked for me. But I don't won't to use this hack because I think it is just sheatcode

Answer (score 2):

I know that you were already asked about credentials, but you may want to double check and make sure that you're providing the Access Key ID and Secret Key for your AWS account, not your SMTP credentials.  Both of these gems use the API as opposed to the SMTP endpoint in order to send messages, so the SMTP credentials are not going to have the appropriate permissions.

If you don't want to use your root AWS account credentials (which is totally understandable), you can create an IAM user and give access to ses:* in the user's policy.

Hopefully that helps!